Home networking with Raspberry Pi as router
I have bunch of computers that I want to convert them into my homelab for experimentation and running kubernetes.
Here is my setup:

Raspberry Pi 5 (RP5) - Ubuntu
Mac Mini - Talos Linux
AMD PC - Talox Linux
Netgear Switch (GS108)

My plan is to run Talos Linux on mac mini and amd pc for running k8s in my home network. Since Talos Linux is very minimal, it does not have support for Wifi, servers have to be hardwired. Mac Mini and AMD PC will be the 2 nodes in talos cluster which has to be wired.
I don't have access to wired connection in my office, so I'm planning on using my RPI5 as a "gateway/router" to share the internet from it's Wifi and forward it over to a switch via ethernet (see diagram).
Both AMD and Mac Mini devices should have access to the internet so that it can pull docker images.
Talos Linux requires the nodes to be on static ip so how do I ensure that Ethernet -> switch is on consistent subnet ? This way the nodes will always be booted to a static ip that was previously known to them.
Are there any other network considerations I have to make? Is there OS/device/software that makes this setup easier? Network doesn't need to be super secure since it's experimental only.


I don't quite understand what you're asking, and what you mean by ensure that Ethernet -> switch is on consistent subnet ? ... if you give the PC,  the Mac and the Pi's eth0 a static IP that's all that needs. And you'll need to use SNAT and masquerading on the Pi for the PC and Mac to be able to talk to the great unwashed. For the laptop to be able to talk to the PC and Mac I would suggest using wireguard or somesuch.

Basically ensure that Ethernet subnet is static at 10.42.0.x. I tried setting up Ubuntu on my pi and setting static ip on eth0 interface but it kept jumping between 10.42.0.x and 192.168.4.x

Pay attention to where your dhcp server is and how it is set up.  Or servers apparently.

Please post your netplan config file from the pi in your question. That doesn't sound right.

In my experience - raspberry pi's wifi sucks for this application, regardless how close the pi is to the AP (at least the 4, not familiar with the 5) - assuming you want decent bandwidth between the two networks - you're better off getting a cheap travel router

Based on the comments, I ended up getting a travel router which did exactly what I was looking for but with better connectivity and stability.
Travel router: https://a.co/d/avcGAkl
